# Storio using rx instead of reactivex

Tags: android, sqlite, rx-java, rx-android, rx-java2

as title says, one of the imports in a file of the Storio dependency defined in my build.gradle is the following:

`import rx.Single`

and Android Studio 3.0 shows an error that says:

`Cannot resolve symbol 'rx'`

First of all, this is the method I'm having problems with:

```
private void demo1(Demo demo) {
    StorIOFactory.get(this)
                .put()
                .object(demo)
                .prepare()
                .asRxSingle()
                .subscribe();
}
```

because I'm getting the error 'Cannot resolve method "subscribe"', so when I search the method 'asRxSingle' in 'PreparedPutObject.java' I found this import:

```
import rx.Single;
```

when according to [this](https://github.com/pushtorefresh/storio/blob/master/storio-sqlite/src/main/java/com/pushtorefresh/storio2/sqlite/operations/put/PreparedPutObject.java#L18), it should be:

```
import io.reactivex.Single;
```

So I guess the issue could be with  my app build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    //other things
    implementation group: 'io.reactivex.rxjava2', name: 'rxandroid', version: '2.0.1'
    implementation group: 'io.reactivex.rxjava2', name: 'rxjava', version: '2.1.5'

    implementation 'com.pushtorefresh.storio2:sqlite:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.pushtorefresh.storio2:content-resolver-annotations:2.1.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.pushtorefresh.storio2:content-resolver-annotations-processor:2.1.0'
}
```

But I keep getting the version of StorIO that imports 'rx.Single'.
Is there a problem with the StorIO version? or with RxJava?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are using auto import of Android Studio or not? `rx.Single` is the legacy Rx 1.x which already deprecated.

Comment: Not deprecated, last release of v1 happened 2 days ago - https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/releases/tag/v1.3.4

Comment: @nhoxbypass That seems to be the issue, but in Storio github repo they use this `import io.reactivex.Single`, so I thought they have made the upgrade already. Maybe my gradle is getting the StorIO with Rx 1.x but I'm not sure why (despite of using 2.1.0 as version)

Answer (score 0):

RxJava and RxJava2 use different packages to allow mixing them together. Find more here - https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What%27s-different-in-2.0#maven-address-and-base-package
So apparently StorIO is using RxJava (version 1).

Comment: It seems to be the case, but their github repo use `import io.reactivex.Single` so I thought they've already been using RxJava2. The issue seems to be that gradle is downloading the StorIO version that uses RxJava